# Copying contents of an array to a multidimensional array using pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, copy

```
 //Given this snippet of code:

    int main() {
        char sample[] = "Hello World";
        char ma[2][6]; 
        char *sptr, *mptr;

        return 0; 
    }
```

I was thinking this through. sptr is the pointer referring to array sample and mptr is the pointer referring to array  ma. Do I first need to reference the pointers to their respective arrays, and     loop through each dimension of the array ma, and increment both of the pointers and set them equal each other? 
 Here is what I have written so far

```
int main(){
char sample[] = "Hello World"; // Create an arry of char  to hold the string "Hello World"
char ma[2][6];    //Create an two dimensional array of char  with 2 rows and  6 columns
char *sptr, *mptr; // Create two pointer variables of type char that are used to copy the content from array sample into array ma
char*sptr = sample;
char*mptr = ma; 
int row;
int column;

for (row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 6; column++){
        *sptr++ = *mptr++;
    }
}



return 0;
```

Comment: Well, you copy 6 bytes of data from one place to another, and since `ma` is 12 bytes, you should be okay. But what were you attempting to accomplish? Copying a 2-dimensional array to a 1-dimensional array rarely makes sense.

Comment: And copying from an uninitialized array to anywhere else never makes sense.

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error. You've redeclared `sptr` and `mptr`. As well as that, you should get a warning that `char*mptr = ma;` initializes an incompatible pointer type. Can you post code that you've actually tried to compile?

Comment: What you are trying to do here? If you are just trying to copy array sample to array ma then you can do a memcpy or strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

Given,

```
char sample[] = "Hello World";
char ma[2][6];
char *sptr, *mptr;
```

It's ok to use

```
sptr = sample;
```

but not

```
char*sptr = sample;
```

You can't define the variable twice.

The line with `mptr` has a different problem. You certainly can't redefine the variable. However, you can't use

```
mptr = ma;
```

In the above statement, `ma` decays to a value whose type is `char (*)[6]`, i.e. a pointer to array of 6 char. The type of `mptr` is not that.

In order to use

```
mptr = ma;
```

you have to define `mptr` as:

```
char (*mptr)[6];
```

In the loop.

```
for (row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 6; column++){
        *sptr++ = *mptr++;
    }
}
```

There are several problems.

The line below is problematic.

```
        *sptr++ = *mptr++;
```

However, that could be attributed to your misunderstanding of how mptr can be used.

Also, your question indicated that you wanted to copy the contents of the 1D array to the 2D array. You need to have an expression involving `mptr` on the LHS of the assignment operator and an expression involving `sptr` on the RHS of the expression.

Then, you have figure out how you want to divide the contents of the 1D array into the 2D array. Do you want the first `6` characters of `sptr` to be in `ma[0]`? Do you want `m[0]` and `m[1]` to be null terminated strings?

And, what to do when the length of the 1D array is too large to fit in the space provided by `ma`. If `ma[0]` and `ma[1]` are to be null terminated strings, `ma` can hold at most a string of length `10`.

And, you have to add the logic to break out of the `for` loop if you have reached the end of the 1D string.

Here's something to get started.

```
for (row = 0; row < 2 && *sptr != '\0'; row++) {

    // No matter when the iteration stops,
    // mptr[row] will be a valid null terminated string.
    mptr[row][0] = '\0';

    // Don't use all the elements of the array.
    // Leave the last element for the terminating null character. 
    for (column = 0; column < 5 && *sptr != '\0'; column++){
        mptr[row][column] = *sptr++;

        // No matter when the iteration stops,
        // mptr[row] will be a valid null terminated string.
        mptr[row][column+1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't ma array undefined still? It is the array sample which needs to be copied to ma is what the question says. sptr points to sample and you are trying to copy contents of array ma which is referenced by mptr to array sample which is not right